# How to get specific string from the email content that store in the SharePoint and show the string in the another column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

If the email store to document library (not as attachments to other list items).

How I could just retrieve the specific string from the email text for the current user and show the result in the another column?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extract the content of an email or any other document using just OOTB functionality. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my case sharepoint received an email that i desgined through sharePoint Designer. When email received in the sharepoint, i would like extract particular string from every email and store in the another column of the same table. Manually, i can copy and paste particular string but i would like to do automatically (like when received the email it will read the email extract particular string.